# spymemcached: how can I tell whether memcached had connected successfully?

Tags: java, spymemcached

I'm using the following library:    `compile 'net.spy:spymemcached:2.12.0'`

So if I do this, if memcachedclient is not connected successfully, it gives me an error:

```
mc.get(myvariable)
```

I want to check the connection status before I call `mc.get()` to prevent the error.

I thought maybe I could check this: `mc.getConnection().connectionsStatus()` but all it does it return a string that says:

```
Connection Status { pub-memcache-XXX active: false, authed: false, last read: 7 ms ago }
```

I thought it would just return a `SUCCESS` or a `FAILURE` but it returns a string.

The doc for the method is here: https://github.com/couchbase/spymemcached/blob/master/src/main/java/net/spy/memcached/MemcachedConnection.java

I have copied the relevant method below:

```
  /**
   * Construct a String containing information about all nodes and their state.
   *
   * @return a stringified representation of the connection status.
   */
  public String connectionsStatus() {
    StringBuilder connStatus = new StringBuilder();
    connStatus.append("Connection Status {");
    for (MemcachedNode node : locator.getAll()) {
      connStatus
        .append(" ")
        .append(node.getSocketAddress())
        .append(" active: ")
        .append(node.isActive())
        .append(", authed: ")
        .append(node.isAuthenticated())
        .append(MessageFormat.format(", last read: {0} ms ago",
          node.lastReadDelta()));
    }
    connStatus.append(" }");
    return connStatus.toString();
  }
```

I don't know, I could parse out the `active` variable and check that but is there an easier way to check whether spymemcached was connected before I call `get` on it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing the `active` variable, you can directly check if the node is active or not by accessing the `MemcachedNode` object for your `MemcachedClient`. You can implement it as shown below:

```
for (MemcachedNode node : mc.getNodeLocator().getAll()) {
        if (!node.isActive()) {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect to Memcached server");
            mc.shutdown();
            //Handle accordingly
        }
}
```

You can use `mc.shutdown()` as `MemcachedClient` continues to reconnect to the server causing your program to hang.